# Fail to invoke class in dynamic loaded DLL from windows service

Tags: c#, windows-services, runtime, invokemember

This is my class in a C# DLL

```
namespace MyNS
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        public static int Execute(string logKey, 
                                  string key, 
                                  XmlNode xmlPars)
        {
            return 0
        }
    }
}
```

I load DLL at run time and load Class Type in to _type variable. But when I call the function Execute from a Windows service like this:

```
counter = (int)_type.InvokeMember("Execute", 
                                  BindingFlags.Public |
                                  BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | 
                                  BindingFlags.Static, 
                                  null, 
                                  null, 
                                  new object[] { 
                                                  logKey, 
                                                  Key, 
                                                  _xmlParams 
                                                });
```

I get "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."
What did I do wrong here?

Comment: At what line the exception is thrown ? I tried a similar example it worked. Can you post how you load the assembly and create type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How you are loading the the DLL, can you please share the code to load the dlls dynamically.?

Here's the sample code.

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("ABC.dll");
object o = Activator.CreateInstance(assembly.GetType("ClassName"));
/// then invoke the method
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.<br/>I load DLL in the same way of yours. Every thing OK but I found that if DLL (my Plugin) reside in different directory of the serivice, and the DLL has references to others DLL. I have to copy other DLLs in to the directory of Windows service instead of Plugin directory.<br/>  The problem is solved now.